# MVC Core Почему не могу сериализовать и десериализовать SelectList?

Tags: html

Нет проблем с этим для обычных списков. Однако с SelectList для организации в представлении выпадающего меню `<select ... </select>` наблюдаются какие-то странности.

```
SelectList fruitSelectList = new SelectList(productsList, "Id", "Name", 2);
string selListString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fruitSelectList);
```

Для проверки делаю обратное преобразование:

```
fruitSelectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SelectList>(selListString);
```

И это уже не исходный объект - элементы списка пропадают.
В итоге для представления в тэге `<select ... >` имею следующую картинку:

[image]

В чём проблема?

Comment: Это вообще что? Какой язык программирования и фреймворк используется? Добавьте метки.

Comment: А зачем вы делаете такое преобразование? В чём смысл?

Comment: Ну, если коротко, то надо! Платформа MVC Core 2022 (C#)

Comment: Сериализация предназначена для передачи _данных_. `SelectList` является _не_ данными, а моделью представления этих данных. Поэтому смысла в его сериализации и передаче куда-то нет.

Comment: Я не понял про модель представления. Всегда считал, что SelectList это класс в пространстве Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering, который может иметь объекты, например:

Comment: Я не понял про модель представления. Всегда считал, что SelectList это класс в пространстве Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering, который может иметь объекты с данными, например:              List<string> list = new List<string>();  SelectList sList = new SelectList(list,"", ""); Этот объект благополучно передаётся с использованием ViewBag без вской серниализации, а вот TempData[...] требует сериализацию. YjViewBag передёт между методом и прикреплённым к нему представлением, а TempData - куда угодно.